# Why does the song plays in the music player even during the incoming call?

Tags: settings, music, calls

I am using Microsoft Lumia 540, I listen to songs in the music player via headset and I generally put my phone in my pocket. When I get a call the music player should stop and default ringtone should play. But its not HAPPENING. The Music player keeps on playing the track even though track keeps playing. This happens when my phone is in "GENERAL mode" . What changes in settings should I make ? 
Update: "General mode means, 
Ringer + Notifications Volume = 10/10
Media + Apps Volume = 30/30

Comment: What is the "General" mode you mentioned?

Comment: General mode means Ringer Volume, Media and Apps Volume are in their maximum value. @RareNCool

Comment: mention whether you're using xbox music(8.10) or groove music (10)

Comment: What music player are you using, and can you confirm if this call is coming in via celluar network, or via a VOIP provider, such as Skype?